# What software can be used for creating a 3D model of this type?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, packaging

I need to create/design a box as shown in images. Basically, to make any ad of this product, I have to take a photo of actual product with camera every time, to fit in any stock image. I have to create the shadows and light effects manually, to make it look realistic fit.

That process takes more time, and at times doesn't look very realistic.

So what I'm thinking is to create a 3D box (I don't know much about these stuff, just saying) in some software and apply light there for shadows, and finally export a PNG of it (whatever angle/view I need) and use it in my ad.

So, the question is: I want it to be a *real* box. Like a bit torn corner and lifted top face you know, so it doesn't look a perfect solid cuboid with sharp edges, but a real box. Can it be done in Photoshop or After Effects? If no, what software can be used to achieve this? I don't want to go into a lot of details, but need the basics (and not very complex to understand) to design a box like this.

[image][image]

Comment: *Any* 3D modeler can do this. From Blender to Sketchup, to Maya and Lightwave. Photoshop *may* be able to but it would be way more work with Photoshop's rudimentary 3D tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question.

Use a 3D program. Take your time to model it, unwrap it and to prepare the lighting and camera angles to match a given scene.

I would use Blender (blender.org) because it has everything you need, again, modeling, texture unwrapping, photorealistic render, you can even track a video to match it, and it's free.

Just take a look at the gallery.

One little thing is that the logic is different than you are probably used to. You need to construct the thing, not only compose an image.

Comment: Okay. Can same things be done in Cinema 4D as well? I've heard it's easy for beginners and Blender is a bit *difficult* at start.

Comment: @Vikas do not choose software based on percieved notion pf easy to beginners. First of it is often a lie, perpetuated by those who chose to use that software. When i teach 3D and investigate this by testing on students i often find that this is not even remotely true. Second chose well, you will likely never have the mental energy to choose another one.

Comment: If you have money to spend, go with Cinema 4D. I had great time with it and everything that concerns motion graphics is so much better in it than in, for instance, Blender. However I abandoned it for Blender just because 80$/month is too much for a hobby. I wouldn't say that Blender is difficult to start with. Maybe way before, but not the latest versions.

Comment: @Rafael which gallery? Link?

Comment: Also, there is a Blender community here on StackExchange :)

Comment: Oh, true, there is no gallery on the org site. Here is one: https://blenderartists.org/c/artwork/forum-gallery and some demo reels: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cycles+demo+reel

Answer (score 0):

It might also work with „Adobe Dimension“, but I do not recommend the software. It’s very limited for adjustments and slow.